# docker-compose.yml: check and switch env values

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am running a basic mongo image from a remote repo (aws/azure) and I want to have a kind of a "switch" where I could check an env variable value and set the image repo to be from either aws or azure. I also have a ".env" file which has few variables.

--> .env

```
# Additional grails arguments, don't use quotes for the value
GRAILS_OPT=

## Docker image ECR repository
CLOUD_PROVIDER=

## Other vars ...
```

--> docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

x-environment:
  # would like to do this..
  IMG_REPO: ${if CLOUD_PROVIDER is 'azure' then set 'azure-registry' else 'default-to-aws'}
  GRAILS_OPT: ${GRAILS_OPT}

services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: ${IMG_REPO}/mongo:3.4
    hostname: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
    - 27017:27017
    volumes:
    - /data/db:/data/db:cached
```

I run this as 
`CLOUD_PROVIDER=azure docker-compose up mongo`

Now before docker-compose goes into pulling the image, i would like to check and switch the provide. If its azure...set it to azure registry OR if its aws...set it to aws ecr !!

I think (I may be wrong as I havent tried this yet !) one way around it would be to create a bash file which would take in the CLOUD_PROVIDER var, set another variable say IMG_REPO to be either az-registry or aws ecr and then call docker-compose.yml. Is there a way to handle this without having to create a bash file ?

Comment: `docker-compose` doesn't support this sort of logic intrinsically. You would need some sort of external script/Makefile/etc to implement the logic.

Comment: @larsks I suppose thats the way it is meant to work..what other ideas you would have other than a script/makefile ??